# How to clone collada model in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I've loaded a `.dae` model, which I would like to use more times in my scene. This code works with meshes, but the `collada.scene` object isn't a mesh:

```
var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( loadedMesh.geometry, loadedMesh.material );
```

How is it possible, to share the same collada model between some objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dae scene is not a mesh, but there's certainly a mesh in it. 
You should console.log the collada object, or put a breakpoint in the `load` function, and inspect where is the mesh you want.

Given a mesh located in `collada.scene.children[0]`

In the `load` function, store the mesh somewhere, say `window.referenceModel`

```
window.referenceModel = collada.scene.children[0];
```

Later, when you want to clone this model

```
var refObject = window.referenceModel;
var clone = new THREE.Mesh( refObject.geometry, refObject.material );
// here you can apply transformations, for this clone only
scene.add( clone );
```