# three.js copy mesh loaded object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im using three.js r59, Im having trouble trying to copy a loaded model. What im trying to achieve is to loop and create several models.I will worry about applying texture to them later..

```
   for (var i=0; i<5-1; i++){

     var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( );
     loader.load( 'mod/bookH.obj',function ( object ) {
     object.traverse( function ( child ) {
     if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
         child.castShadow = true;
         console.log(i);
         //child.material.map = texture;  //dont need right now

        }

    } );
        //below works
            object.position.set( 1 * 0, 0, 5 );
        scene.add( object );

            //below doesn't work and no error...
            var testMesh = new.THREE.Object3D(object);
            scene.add(testMesh);


    });  
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want N instances of the same mesh, you don't need to load them N times; just load it once, and create N new meshes with the same geometry.

My answer on a similar question : [How to clone collada model in threejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942539/how-to-clone-collada-model-in-threejs/18978242#18978242)

Hope this helps

Comment: i used a cloned method instead of new.THREE.Mesh...my loaded model was a object3D,could get the mesh.. I instead  pushed it in each item into an array then added it to the scene once completed in a separate loop again ... your approach should of work but didn't anyways thank you.